# WPF ボタンのbackgroundを変更後、元に戻したい

Tags: wpf

こんにちは。
以下のようなコードを組んでいます。
XAML

```
<Button Background="{Binding BGButton.Value}"....略>
```

CS

```
public ReactiveProperty<string> BGButton { get; private set; }
private dummy()
{
  if(boolFlg) {
    BGButton = new ReactiveProperty<string>("#FFFF0000"); //赤　これはＯＫ
  }
  else {
    BGButton = //ここで見た目をデフォルトに戻したい
//new ReactiveProperty<string>("#FFDDDDDD");　これは違う
  }
}
```

条件でボタンの色を変更したいのですが、その後元に戻す方法が分かりません。
FFDDDDDDを指定すれば色は戻りますが、元の立体的な表示ではなく、２Ｄの一色表示となってしまいます。

条件がfalseの時は、BGButtonの指定を無視してくれるような仕組みにできればいいのですが。
そもそもバインドで色を指定する方法がダメなのかも、判断がつかず困っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己解決しました。デフォルト表示が３Ｄだと思っていたのですが、別にStaticResourceを定義していたために、そう見えていただけでした。よってifelseの結果をBGButton に入れて、Trigger PropertyにてFFFF0000か、StaticResourceのいずれかをセットすることで対応できました。